# Laravel automatic translation

Tags: laravel, translation

I am using laravel 5.2 and I have to translate huge bulks of text which has to be translated to multiple language. Is there a way to automatically translate the content. And if there is , what are the chances of getting correct translation.

Comment: Hi, I'm currently working on a package which does exactly what you need. I'm looking for beta testers, so hit me up (p.mohr at sopamo.de) when you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

For that purpose you need to use laravel's Localization.

Read this documentation and create localization in your project.

```
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/localization
```

And you just use `Lang.get();` when you need to get different language.
I am currently working on project which have 3 different languages. May be this helps you.I am new to laravel.:)

Comment: I have used the localization in my other projects, however i have to go to each lang file and create the individual translation which takes too much of my time. I was searching for something that could automate my work.

Comment: @Rookie Coder Yes, by using localization you have to create individual translation language files. Sorry, I have not idea about automate translation.